# How can I enforce creation of *.aux files?

Tags: cross-referencing, auxiliary-files, subfiles, xr, gummi

I want to write a thesis using `subfiles` and `xr` for external references. I use `subfiles` because that allows me to compile chapters separately without having to compile the whole thesis. My problem is that the cross-references between different subfiles don't work because of missing auxiliary files.

The cross-references in the output of the the main document are correct, but if I compile a subfile, then the cross-references to the other subfile are just question marks. In the build log it says

> Package xr Warning: No file main.aux.

The editor I am using is Gummi on Ubuntu 20.04 and in the compilation options I chose *TeXLive with pdfTeX*. I also tried choosing *TeXLive with XeteX*, *TeXLive with LuateX*, and *LateXmk*, but none of it solved the problem.

As I understand from the comments, something (Gummi?) is deleting the `.aux` files after the compilation.

When I compile from terminal (using `pdfatex` or `latexmk`), then all the `.aux` files are created and as a result I get the cross-references also in the subfiles. (But I don't want to compile from terminal every time I make some changes that affect cross-references. The reason why I am using Gummi is that it has instant live preview so that I don't have to hit a compile button every thirty seconds.)

Where and how can I change the settings of Gummi or of whatever is deleting the files to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: that is not really a latex question but a question about your editor and the tool it uses to compile. Obviously they are cleaning up after the compilation, but you will have to find the suitable settings to disable this. Showing your latex code doesn't help here.

Comment: by default the aux file is written in the same directory as your source,  personally I wouldn't use subfiles which complicates the issue and just include the chapters then you don't need xr at all. I wrote xr but not really for this use.

Comment: note hitting the compile button every few seconds should be a non-aim, and getting your editor to do it for you isn't that useful either. You should be able to write a page or two's worth of tex source without needing to run it through latex.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more precise. @ David Carlisle If I just include the chapter (with ```\include```), then I cannot compile the chapter separately. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You're missing something.  `\includeonly{...}` allows one ro compile *only* the specified chapters, but all existing `.aux` files are automatically included, so cross references that have already been resolved will be shown properly.

Answer (score 2):

It's rare that `subfiles` is a better solution than the LaTeX kernel's `\include`/`\includeonly` mechanism.¹

In this case, I think you would definitely be better served by abandoning `subfiles`. Instead, your individual chapters would get rid of everything except what's between `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. The main document would load the chapters with `\include{FILE}` for each file named `FILE.tex` (note that the extension *must* be omitted on the `\include` statement). Finally in the preamble of the main document, you would put `\includeonly{FILE}` to indicate that only `FILE` should be typeset. When you run the whole document (without `\includeonly`—I usally comment out the whole `\includeonly` line ) LaTeX will create an `aux` file for each file that's loaded with `\include` and retain page numbers and `\label` definitions and read those all in.

So you'll have a main file that looks like:

```
\documentclass{thesis}
...
% \includeonly{analysis} % uncomment this line to only run analysis

\begin{document}
\include{frontmatter}
\include{introduction}
\include{methods}
\include{analysis}
\appendix
\include{appendices}
\end{document}
```

with files like:

```
\chapter{Analysis}
Lots of text here
```

I recommend having things like `\maketitle`, `\tableofcontents`, etc. be gathered together in a single file included as well. Commands like `\frontmatter`, `\mainmatter`, `\endmatter` or `\appendix` should be in the main file.

You will always run LaTeX against the main file and not the individual chapters. Your IDE should have some mechanism to allow you to specify the main file within included files or possibly for a whole project. For example, in emacs, putting something like the following in the file indicates that the main file is `../ltxbook.tex`

```
%%% Local Variables:
%%% mode: latex
%%% TeX-master: "../ltxbook"
%%% End:
```

Be aware that when generating an index², you will need to run the whole file before running makeindex since the `.idx` file will not include `\index` entries from chapters that were omitted by `\includeonly`.

---

1. I'll admit that I may be subject to selection bias because most of my exposure to `subfiles` is people having problems getting it to work, but I have yet to see a compelling argument on its behalf. I suspect that a lot of the use of `subfiles` is cargo-culting from users who are unaware of the whole `\include` mechanism.
2. Or any other tool that uses makeindex, like some glossary tools

Comment: I was indeed unaware of this mechanism. Good to know! Unfortunately, with this approach I could not use the instant live preview feature of Gummi. (Gummi compiles automatically every second or so, so I usually notice immediately if I make a mistake. But it compiles only the file I am editing, so if I am editing something without preamble, then I don't get any preview.)

Comment: @Insa For gummi, you would need to set up a "Project" go to your root document, go to project in the menu bar and select new. From there you can add the other files in the project to the list and you should be able to still use the live preview feature with gummy running the main file.

Comment: I set up a project as you suggested, but the behavior of Gummi is still the same. I don't see any possibility of editing a chapter while having the live preview of the main file. Is there something else I have to do to make it possible?